# How can I correct my review of a tag-edit?

Tags: support

I accidentally *approved* a tag edit which I meant to *reject*? (sorry)

Is there a way for me to undo that approval and reject it? Or at least remove my approval? The edit was a copy of a piece of a manufacturers marketing 'blurb', and IMHO not helpful.

I've dug around the help centre, and my profile, but I can't see a way to remove my approval.

I have looked at the tag and it is in 'edit pending" state, and has one approval (mine :-( and one rejection. It really should be two rejections.

Comment: If you explain *which* tag, maybe a mod can help.

Comment: @OlinLathrop - Thank you for the comment. I thought about doing that when I asked the question. However I am slightly nervous about mentioning the tag as I believe the person was a regular user, and they might take offence, and I assume others could figure out who edited the tag, and maybe even disadvantage them. I'd prefer to declare that I am a bit of a twit, rather than cause offence to others.

Comment: That's just plain silly.  Putting how someone might feel ahead of the site is bad practice.  If what they did was reasonable, then they won't be insulted.  If they in fact did something stupid, then they have to live getting called on it.  We are here to talk about electrical engineering, not to pander to the assumed fragilities of individual users.  Get into the real world.

Comment: @OlinLathrop - I live in the real world, and it is mostly PC. I believe you have complained about various down-voting behaviours, and proposing means to change those behaviours. Yet the community decided to *not* change. So I don't think your relationship with the *'real world'* is demonstrably better than mine. People are from different cultures and backgrounds. Some of us try to be polite, some of us might think that is a waste of effort. I don't. Further, I don't appreciate you asserting your view of moral, rational, justifiable, or 'correct' on me. Merry Christmas, and Happy New Year.

Comment: In the future, if the edit is approved because of a fat finger mistake, just roll it back, with an appropriate edit note like `Bad edit because of X and Y`. If it gets re-edited, then flag it for a moderator to decide.

Comment: @Passerby - Thank you for the advice. I don't have the rep to use tag editing directly. So, is 'roll it back' functionality available when the tag is no longer in 'edit pending'? Or do you mean that I need to manually edit the tag back to its previous text?

Comment: Roll back is in the edit history. You do need to wait until its no longer edit pending. It does count as a manual edit, so if you lack the rep it will into the edit review queue.

Comment: @Passerby - Thanks again. I wish you a Happy New Year!

Answer (score 1):

I've just put the second reject on the wiki edit you're talking about, it was pretty easy to spot as a 5k user from the recent review list which one you meant because it was the only one you'd approved recently still pending with another rejection. In general though for wiki edits there's no way to undo your approval but:

- The idea of needing multiple approvals is so that if you occasionally fat-finger one which is easy enough to do it will hopefully end up being rejected anyway.
- But it's probably a good idea to make a note of it so if it does slip through you can suggest an edit later to fix it.
- You could also raise a moderator flag on any post including a link to the review and explain you'd wrongly approved it, although personally I probably wouldn't bother moderators with it unless it was something like blatant spam.

I noticed some of the same user's other wiki edits have been rejected as "spam or destructive" by others. While they do sound spam-like they are copies of various manufacturer product pages, so the "copied content" rejection reason that you'd been using on the previous edits is more appropriate in my opinion. Normally when reviewing wiki edits I plug an entire sentence into Google, a lot of suggestions are straight copies of manufacturer or Wikipedia pages.

Comment: Thank you for the information, and thank you for fixing it. After I made the mistake, I'd hoped there'd be the, maybe time limited, ability to change my vote, like other votes. Now I know better. I discovered that it was "manufacturer's marketing blurb" by pasting a big chunk of it into a search engine. That was partly the reason I was annoyed at myself when I 'fat-finger Approved'. Merry Christmas and Happy New Year.